# sunion command in redis return wrong result

Tags: redis, command

I have a key "726fa624_F_2001#1#N" which is bound to a Set,the Set contains "yahoo.com,google.com,facebook.com,twitter.com".
I have another key "726fa624_F_2000#1#N" which is bound to a Set,the Set contains "newstime.com,myspace.com,amazon.com".

Now when I execute "SUNION 726fa624_F_2001#1#N 726fa624_F_2000#1#N" command through redis-cli,I expect the result to be a Set which contains "yahoo.com,google.com,facebook.com,twitter.com,newstime.com,myspace.com,amazon.com",but the real result is "yahoo.com,google.com,facebook.com,twitter.com"

what is the problem with it.
Thanks for your help!

The CLI session is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1:6000> SMEMBERS 726fa624_F_2201#1#N
1) "vpgboh.com"
2) "vpfbkt.com"
3) "vpgboe.com"
127.0.0.1:6000> SMEMBERS 726fa624_F_2202#1#N
1) "vpgboo.com"
2) "126.com"
3) "vpgbos.com"
4) "vpgbor.com"
127.0.0.1:6000> SUNION 726fa624_F_2201#1#N 726fa624_F_2202#1#N
1) "vpgboh.com"
2) "vpfbkt.com"
3) "vpgboe.com"
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the CLI session

Comment: Hi,I add the CLI session in the problem description,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not reproduce

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS 726fa624_F_2201#1#N
1) "vpgboe.com"
2) "vpfbkt.com"
3) "vpgboh.com"
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS 726fa624_F_2202#1#N
1) "126.com"
2) "vpgbos.com"
3) "vpgboo.com"
4) "vpgbor.com"
127.0.0.1:6379> SUNION 726fa624_F_2201#1#N 726fa624_F_2202#1#N
1) "vpgboh.com"
2) "vpgboo.com"
3) "vpgboe.com"
4) "vpfbkt.com"
5) "vpgbor.com"
6) "126.com"
7) "vpgbos.com"
```

Which Redis version are you using?

Comment: I am using redis-cli 3.0.2

Comment: Are there other, possibly data modifying, commands being run at the same time as yours? Could you perhaps add `DUMP`'s output for these two sets?

Comment: I think I have found the reason myself.We are using Redis Cluster and there  is a limitation in Redis Cluster Usage.That is commands dealing with multiple keys are not supported by the Redis Cluster (SINTER, SUNION, …).It can be found in [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/redis-clustering.html) @Itamar Haber

Comment: I don't think so - the cluster replies with CROSSSLOT error if you're trying to use a multi-key command across hash slots.